# make it as a single object in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, object

I have json body as shown below

```
let data = [
  {country: 'India', state: 'Maharastra', population: 1000},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Karanataka', population: 800},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Kerla', population: 200},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Telangana', population: 700}
];
```

expected output

```
op = [{country: 'India', state1:1000, state2: 800, state3:200, state4: 700, Total: 2700}]
```

is there any way we can convert this into a single array object? is this achievable on typescript?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That seems to be a very odd requirement. Why wouldn't you use just an array to hold all the different populations if the state names obviously don't matter? So it would look like this `{country: 'India', popPerState: [1000, 800, 200, 700], Total: 2700}`.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing. This is how server returning the data and for display purpose I have to convert into the expected op format

Comment: @Angular_dev any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

```ts
const data = [
  {country: 'India', state: 'Maharastra', population: 1000},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Karanataka', population: 800},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Kerla', population: 200},
  {country: 'India', state: 'Telangana', population: 700}
];

const indexedStates = data.map((stateData, index) => 
({country: stateData.country, 
   [`state${index+1}`]: stateData.state, 
   [`population${index+1}`]: stateData.population
  })
)

const total =  data.reduce((sum, stateData) => sum + stateData.population, 0);

const finalValue = Object.assign({},...indexedStates, {total});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvUAVzCgCcBPALhgHIBJMOASwRoBoZokBTamgWQQALBKQTQx7GAAcQ0wgBskTcNQCMABi0BfNjnxESFPg2asOXKL1oBpUQjBIEAa3My5i5apgAOHXtwCEGIyKlpTFilLaxobblIlKVl5JSgVMGoAJn99IJDjcMZIi2QrPgAVbiUwAHMHN2TPNO8Adh0sAF0AbiwsUEhYJkZuAA9uOABlUu4INHgnADoAWwRpAAo16IARJw4huFGASjQAPhgsNbyjMO3Fw1COfUwAA2iAEjx90YBqNW1njrUW7IBbRR64F6NVLpD5fEa-f6AzjTHYgqFeMD6bSHLA4vrgaAwKAgZAKObzEGkcaEYDcDYQQhLEo8VEIY6oM4MpYwb7IlmLdHNMAcDSHHr4gYwABmQwQCgAanLCNw5gB5ABGACtuMAoAtxBAmDUwJddAtzXDxlMeBAOHhiaTsT1+hAQApuAsFCAamsZY4FUruGKgA)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce()`

```
let data = [
   { country: 'India', state: 'Maharastra', population: 1000 },
   { country: 'India', state: 'Karanataka', population: 800 },
   { country: 'India', state: 'Kerla', population: 200 },
   { country: 'India', state: 'Telangana', population: 700 }
];

const result = data.reduce<{ [key: string]: any }>((acc, val, i) => {
   acc.country = val.country;
   acc[`state${i + 1}`] = val.population;
   acc.total = val.population + (isNaN(acc.total) ? 0 : acc.total);
   return acc;
}, {});
```